# Image must be added to group before group added to layer?

Tags: konvajs

I'm finding a potential bug in KonvaJS. Or I'm not sure about the capabilities...

1) Create a layer and add it to stage

2) Create a group and add it to layer

3) Create an Image node and add it to group (Note my images are loaded using Konva.Image.fromURL which waits for the image to load then adds it to the group.)

Result: Image does not appear.

But if you add the image to the group then add the group to the layer, the image appears. This is going to cause problems if I want to attach an image to a group dynamical if it just disappears.

I'm trying to create the concept of a tray or plate. Where the user can place items onto the plate. If the user drags the plate it creates a group with all the intersecting nodes and moves them all together. At drag end it releases all the objects back to the user.

EDIT: The problem I was experiencing had to do with group coordinates as I mentioned in my comment bellow.

"I think I misunderstood, for the longest time how positioning works with groups. Read the comments: jsfiddle.net/jusatx6s"

LL: Make sure you're checking the position of the nodes your are rendering and that they do appear on screen.

Comment: Hi. Can you create a demo?

Comment: I think I misunderstood, for the longest time how positioning works with groups. Read the comments: https://jsfiddle.net/jusatx6s/

Comment: I have not hit this issue myself so wonder, as per @jefhai, if you are setting (x, y) on the image. Co-ordinates in grouped elements can be confusing as the group origin is the top & left of the top-left-most element in the group.  Try setting (x,y) to zero and see what you get.

Comment: I have made a minimal viable example below that does what you describe. Please could you see if you can edit it and make it fail as per your case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a plunkr and followed steps which you have mentioned. Everything is working fine. Here's my code.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});
// 1. created layer added it to stage.
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
// 2. created group added it to layer
var group = new Konva.Group({
        x: 120,
        y: 40,
        rotation: 20
});

layer.add(group);
var src = 'https://konvajs.github.io/assets/yoda.jpg';
// 3. Create an Image node and add it to group
Konva.Image.fromURL(src, function(yoda) {
  console.log(yoda);
  yoda.setAttrs({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    width: 106,
    height: 118
  });
  // 4. Add it to group.
  group.add(yoda);
  layer.batchDraw(); // It's required to draw changes.
});
```

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/znAcWO2ReF7xwZN8ptjn?p=preview) to play around. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: What does `batchDraw();` do? I can't find it in the API docs under Layer.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually really useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Edited in light of OP's edit re confusion over co-ordinates.

Principles:

1. layers use the same co-ordinate system as the stage. So setting a shape position to {X: 10, y: 20} is at 10,20 in relation to the top left of the stage.
2. Adding a shape to a group is different, but you will not notice this if you do not set the group x & y position. For shapes that are added to the group, the shape positions are ADDED to the parent group positions.

Here is an example using a layer and a group. The gold rect is on the layer only. The group is illustrated by the green rect and has been set to position (60, 50). The red rect is a copy of the gold rect except the color. It has the same x & y position as red, BUT it is added to the group. And so its position (5, 5) is added to the group position (60, 50) to give its absolute position on the stage as (65, 55).

```js
// add a stage
var s = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});

// add a layer        
var l = new Konva.Layer();
s.add(l);

// Add a gold rect to the LAYER
var gold = new Konva.Rect({stroke: 'gold', width: 40, height: 50, x: 5, y: 5});
l.add(gold);

// add a group
var g = new Konva.Group({x:60, y:50});
l.add(g);

// Add a green rect to the LAYER then add to the group
var green = new Konva.Rect({stroke: 'lime', width:100, height: 100, x: 0, y: 0});
g.add(green);

// Add a red rect, same apparent co-ords as red, but this time to the group
var red = new Konva.Rect({stroke: 'red', width: 40, height: 50, x: 5, y: 5});
g.add(red);

var abspos = red.getAbsolutePosition();
var pos = red.position();
console.log('Abs position of red is (' + abspos.x + ', ' + abspos.y + ') but its co-ords are ' + '(' + pos.x + ', ' + pos.y + ')'); 
  l.draw(); // redraw the layer it all sits on.
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.2/konva.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the added example. My problem ended up being related to how group coordinates worked. I figured it out and made an edit to the original question.

Comment: @jefhai Sorry saw that comment but did not connect it to you. I had a few initial misunderstandings with groups too. I ended up adding to the group an invisible background rect that is the size of the stage thus giving me group co-ordinates that match to the page.